# Tomcat not responding after undeploying docs and examples application

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

For security reasons, I wanted to remove docs and examples application. So, at first, I deleted both of them from the webapps directory. However, the remaining applications were not responding in browser, although the tomcat service is running in the server. I got blank screens.

Then I put back docs and examples in webapps directory, and things were back again. Then, I tried to undeploy them using tomcat manager. The undeployment works, but again I got blank screens.

I even tried restricting access to apps using valve and filters. And unfortunately, again I get blank screens.

Permission is not an issue, all contents belong to the tomcat user.

I am using Tomcat 8.5.37.

**Update**: I started with a clean installation. However, I get same result after undeploying docs and examples.

**Update**: I think it should be mentioned that we are using aws environment, and there is a load balancer. Also, in front of Tomcat we are using Apache (ajp_proxy).

Comment: What exception messages (if any) are you receiving from the tomcat logs?  I just tried what you said on a tomcat docker image (removing the ../webapps/docs/ and ../webapps/examples/ directories and the tomcat instance kept running and serving the default homepage.  What urls are you trying to access?

Comment: I did not receive any error message (catalina.out), and from the linux console if I see the status of the Tomcat service, it is also running fine. The issue is tomcat is serving blank, white page in browser: for manager application, and my deployed ROOT application.

Comment: May be to reproduce the issue, you can deploy any other application to replace the default homepage that comes with Tomcat.